# how to install "bsdtar" instead of busybox "tar" in yocto build

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, libarchive

I need bsdtar, bsdcpio binaries provided by libarchive package to be installed in the rootfs instead of busybox-tar and busybox-cpio.

Tried changing the ALTERNATIVE_PRIORITY = "10" in the libarchive bb file but that doesn't install bsdtar in the rootfs

```
ALTERNATIVE_PRIORITY = "10"

PACKAGES =+ "bsdtar"
FILES_bsdtar = "${bindir}/bsdtar"

ALTERNATIVE_bsdtar = "tar"
ALTERNATIVE_LINK_NAME[tar] = "${base_bindir}/tar"
ALTERNATIVE_TARGET[tar] = "${bindir}/bsdtar"

PACKAGES =+ "bsdcpio"
FILES_bsdcpio = "${bindir}/bsdcpio"

ALTERNATIVE_bsdcpio = "cpio"
ALTERNATIVE_LINK_NAME[cpio] = "${base_bindir}/cpio"
ALTERNATIVE_TARGET[cpio] = "${bindir}/bsdcpio"
```

Busybox ALTERNATIVE_PRIORITY = "50"